# Wrong ID returned from local Eloquent scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

In my Laravel project I've got a model (and an underlying table) for lessons. Now I'm trying to write a local scope for returning all lessons that have been finished by a particular user. The definition of "finished" is that there exists a row in a table named "lesson_results" with this lesson's ID and the users ID.

My scope currently looks like this:

```
public function scopeFinished($query, User $user)
{
    return $query->join('lesson_results', function($join) use($user)
        {
            $join->on('lesson_results.lesson_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
            ->where("user_id", $user->id);
        });
}
```

This kinda works. When I do a Lesson::finished($user)->get() I get out the correct lessons for that user. However the lessons in the collection returned all have the wrong ID's! The ID's I see are the ID's from the lesson_results table. So when I check $lesson->id from one of the returned items I don't get the ID from that lesson, but the ID from the corresponding row in the lesson_results table.

I've checked in mysql and the full query sent from Laravel is the following

```
select * from `lessons` inner join `lesson_results` on `lesson_results`.`lesson_id` = `lessons`.`id` and `user_id` = 53
```

This query DO return two columns named id (the one from the lessons table and the one from the lesson_results table) and it seems Laravel is using the wrong one for the result returned.

I don't know if I'm going about this the wrong way or if it's a bug somewhere?

This is on Laravel 7.6.1.

edit: Ok, I think I actually solved it now. Not really sure though if it's a real solution or just a workaround. I added a select() call so the return row now is

```
return $query->select('lessons.*')->join('lesson_results', function($join) use($user)
```

...which makes it only return the stuff from the lessons table. But should that really be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the same column names will be covered by the other.

### Solution 1:

Specify the table with the column, and alias the other table's column if it has same column name.

```php
Lesson::finished($user)->select('lessons.*', 'lesson_results.id AS lesson_result_id', 'lesson_results.column1', 'lesson_results.column2',...)->get();
```

### Solution 2:

Or you can use Eloquent-Builder eager-loading `whereHas`,(Assuming you have build the relationship between model `Lesson` and model `LessonResult`)

```php
public function scopeFinished($query, User $user)
{
    return $query->whereHas('lessonResults', function($query) use($user)
        {
            $query->where("user_id", $user->id);
        });
}
```

So you can get lesson like this:

```php
Lesson::finished($user)->get();
```

Comment: Yep. Definitely going with solution 2. A bit nicer than the one I came up with myself :-)

Also guess I'll have to review other parts of my code, I'm sure I have done this on other occations as well. Guess it has been pure luck that I've been getting the correct ID back...